# javascript $(this).data() not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code that sends a value to a database using ajax. However, my alert box shows `undefined` for the value. I don't understand what my problem is.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#publish', function(){

            var status = $(this).data('data-pid');
            alert(status);
            $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'update_about_status.php',
                data: {"statusValue": status},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $('.modal-box').text(result).fadeIn(700, function() 
                    {
                        setTimeout(function() 
                        {
                            $('.modal-box').fadeOut();
                        }, 2000);
                     });
                }
            });
        });
    });         

</script>
print'<button type="button" id="publish" class="btn btn-info" data-pid="'.$cd[$i][3].'">Make Publish</button>';
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api, there is no need to have the `data-` prefix to read the `data-*` attribute value - see [data-html5](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

```
var status = $(this).data('pid');
```

If you are using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) then you need to use the complete attribute name like

```
var status = $(this).attr('data-pid');
```

Comment: I already done correction to var status = $(this).data('pid'); But show undefined

Comment: @shanto: Then you have a different problem, which is not visible the in the code you posted.

Comment: @shanto see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hw9Hf/1/ - also share the generated html and try to recreate the problem in the fiddle

Comment: @ArunPJohny I know this is years later but the issue still exists I believe, here's an example. Check the jsfiddle console output and you'll notice ".data(): undefined". https://jsfiddle.net/dannycabrera/5rhobguz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to give `data-` in parameter of `data()` function but you have to give only give `pid`, The `data-` is used to identify the data attributes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Rpr/1/)**

```
var status = $(this).data('pid');
```

> Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes
>
> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters, [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Comment: I already done correction to var status = $(this).data('pid'); But show undefined

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing to:

```
var status = $(this).data('pid');
```